# how to change UIPickview height

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have seen so many posts but none of them gives answer for this question. How to change this? Can anyone please help with it?

Thank you,

Ankita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the height of the pickerView as it is kept fixed  by Apple.

Hence it does not allow you to change its height.

If you want more flexibility you may go for some custom created controls available on internet that would enable you to have more freedom over setting the size and all.

**NOTE:**

Please keep in mind that the more custom controls you use, the more are the chances of your app getting rejected by Apple.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: ohk. Thanks for your help. Let me try that out.

Comment: Ankita you shud go for standard picker because as @PARTH said custom controls may cause rejection

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: I am glad that it helped you. :)

Comment: @Anjali Pradhan: Exactly the same point.Thanks for the support. :]